# Ribbon embroidery

Tags: sewing, embroidery

I am very interested in ribbon embroidery but don't have much idea about it.
Can anyone help me with the type of cloth, needles and ribbon needed to start with embroidery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Caneva hand sewing needles with dull tip. Also, a ribbon of about 0.7 mm is easy to handle. Take a look at ideas on Pinterest (https://www.pinterest.co.uk/), usually, they have DIY ideas and tutorials

Comment: What is a Caneva needle? If it's a brand, please could you edit your answer to explain a little about the properties of these needles, and why they're good for ribbon embroidery?